# is it possible to use data annotation validation for Not Mapped field in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, data-annotations

```
 public class tblStudentAddress :UpdateDates
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentAddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public virtual tblStudent tblStudent { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "PinCode is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{6}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid PinCode")]
    public int StudentPincode { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{6}(-\d{6})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip")]

    public int StudentTempPinCode { get; set; }
```

The value of the StudentTempPincode is save as the next row of studentAddressTable with same studentId (can add mutiple pincodes) . I tried this its shows some error like

> entity validation error  in StudentTempPinCode

Comment: As a general rule, you don't want to use your data models as view models.

Comment: Avoid using validation attributes for properties marked with `NotMappedAttribute` - doing so may result in unexpected behavior. Also keep database model & viewmodel separate each other.

Comment: sorry for making confusion tblStudentAddress is simply a model  i am using it in StudentViewModel which is a viewmodel (thats why i tagged it as viewmodel) @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: How could that regex possible result in an `int`. And take note of the previous 2 comments. Delete `StudentTempPinCode` from your data model and use it only in your view model (which is completely separate from your data model)

Comment: okay thankyou! is there any other way to do validation for the "StudentTempPinCode"  @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: oky ! @StephenMuecke thank you

Comment: @StephenMuecke sir can u please explain how it  work by putting on viewmodel

Comment: From you previous comments, I assume your `StudentViewModel` has a property which is `tblStudentAddress` which is wrong. View models do not contain properties which are data models - they contain the properties of your data model(s) that you need in the view, so `StudentViewModel` will contain a property `[RegularExpression(@"^\d{6}(-\d{6})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip")]public string StudentTempPinCode { get; set; }` (and note it needs to be `string` not `int` - an `int` cannot contain a hyphen)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  so should i write each  property i need from each data model in the studentViewmodel  now my studentViewmodel is like

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you should be doing. And then you map you data models to the view models in the GET method, and vice-versa in the POST method when saving

Comment: ' public  class StudentViewModel 
    {
        public tblStudent Student { get; set; }

        public tblStudentAddress  StudentAddress { get; set; }

        public tblStudentDocument StudentDocuments { get; set; }
} '  Now my viewmodel look like dis  so is this  a wrong practice @StephenMuecke

Comment: That is not good practice. View models should not contain properties which are data models.

Comment: oky thank you sir now i understood  @StephenMuecke  So i should write all the properties into Studentviewmodel one by one and do the validation there in view model